# Entityframework error: "The type '......' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having trouble generating an IQuerable result from a group by clause in linq to Entities for range of values.

```
    IQueryable<Model.MyEntity> query = MyContext.GetDbSet()      
    IQueryable<MyObject> query2 = null;
        query2 = query.Select(x => new MyObject()
        {           

            GroupingColumn = SqlFunctions.StringConvert(arrayMin.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(s => x.Amount > s)) + 
            "-" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert(arrayMax.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(s => x.Amount < s)) ,
        CountOfAmountRange = 1,
             SumOfAmount = (decimal)x.Amount,
        });
        query2 = query2.GroupBy(cm => new {cm.GroupingColumn }).Select(y => new MyObject()
        {
            GroupingColumn =y.Key.GroupingColumn ,
            CountOfAmountRange = y.Count(),
            SumOfAmount = (decimal)y.Sum(p => p.SumOfAmount)
      });
```

A bit of context:
I am working on a highly structured application which has a layer responsible for generating queries which will be later applied to retrieve data from context in another layer. I have successfully used this to generate many reports but this specific one throws the error below.

> The type 'MyObject' appears in two structurally incompatible
>       initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be
>       initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same
>       properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

The arrayMax and arrayMin are arrays of decimal values containing the maximum and minimum values respectively for comparison and generating of string values for the GroupingColumn.

I have seen a couple of questions relating this error on StackOverflow but none of the answers seem to show me the solution to my problem.

Comment: Kind of hard to read what your code is intended to do but since you only really use the type in the second half, try replacing the first use with an anonymous type.  'query2 = query.Select(x => new MyObject()' -> ' query2 = query.Select(x => new '

Comment: Thanks alun. That seemed to stop the error. It created new errors in the code though but thats my part to fix now. Thanks alot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139402/the-type-appears-in-two-structurally-incompatible-initializations-within-a-singl)

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, this SO duplicate (added one year later) was key to solving my problems:

[The type appear in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074109/the-type-appear-in-two-structurally-incompatible-initializations-within-a-single)

When you look at it, the error message is abundantly clear. Don't mess up the initialization order if you are instantiating an object more than once in the same Linq expression. For me, I instantiated a type conditionally, but with different initialization orders.