# MySQL - Where Issues with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

This query works.

```
string value = null;
var temp1 = (from d in db.Device
             where                                 
                (value == null ? true : d.Status == 1)
              select d).ToList();
```

But this query does not work.

```
string value = null;
var temp1 = (from d in db.Device
             where                                 
                (value == null ? true : d.Status == 1)
              select d).OrderBy(i => i.Title).ToList();
```

`Device` model has `Status` and `Title` properties.

Error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

`MySql.Data` Version: 6.9.9

`Connector/Net`: 6.9.9

```
MySql.Data.Entity.EF6
```

Just add orderby and get the error. Could you tell me why?

StackTrace:

```
  at MySql.Data.Entity.CaseFragment.Accept(SqlFragmentVisitor visitor) at MySql.Data.Entity.BinaryFragment.Accept(SqlFragmentVisitor visitor) at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.FuseSelectWithInnerSelect(SelectStatement outer, SelectStatement inner)    at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.TryFusingSelect(InputFragment f)    at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)    at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type)    at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)    at MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. How the exception stack trace looks like?

Comment: is it possible to do the ordering after executing the query? that means .ToList().OrderBy()? if this works, it might be a query generation problem.

Comment: Are you open to using lambda expressions?

Comment: @IvanStoev Added stack trace. Cold you check it again?

Comment: Well, it's not your code, but some MySQL connector internal expression visitor code, so definitely it's a MySQL connector bug.

Comment: Can't test right now on MySQL, could you try replacing `(value == null ? true : d.Status == 1)` with `(value == null || d.Status == 1)` and see if it works (as workaround).

Comment: @Cer the `where` clause doesn't make much sense. It looks like you are trying to rewrite a catch-all query as LINQ. You *DON'T* need catch-all queries with LINQ. Just *DON'T* include `Where()` if you don't need it

Comment: @IvanStoev Worked. I am embarrassed that this method does not come to mind. But the above method seems like a bug. If you can write as answer, I mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Cer you posted a LINQ-to-EF question. This has nothing to do with jQuery. If you want to use an *optional* `Where()` clause, you can easily use the fluent LINQ syntax to construct the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to rewrite a catch-all query as LINQ. You *don't* need to write a catch-all query at all with LINQ, you can simply ignore the condition if you don't want it, eg:

```
string value=someOptionalParameter;
var query = (value==null)? db.Device : db.Where(d=>d.Status == 1);    
var temp1 =  query.OrderBy(d=>d.Title).ToList();
```

In this case, `value` isn't used at all. It's just used as a flag. If you *did* want to use it, eg to optionally filter by a `Category` field, you could use it in the where clause in the same way:

```
string value=someOptionalParameter;
var query = (value==null)? db.Device : db.Where(d=>d.Category == value);    
var temp1 =  query.OrderBy(d=>d.Title).ToList();
```

In general, you can "build" the query bit by bit. An `IQueryable< T>` isn't translated into SQL until you try to enumerate it and/or convert it to a List, Array etc. You could create a query dynamically from a user's options like this:

```
var query = dbContext.MyEntity;
if (someField != null)
{
    query = query.Where(d=>d.SomeField = someField);
}

if (someOtherField != null)
{
    query = query.Where(d=>d.SomeOtherField = someField);
}

if (mustOrder != null)
{
    query = query.OrderBy(d=>d.OrderField);
}

//Execute the final query
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: This approach will be better. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to the stack trace, it's a MySQL connector bug in processing the `? :` operator part (`CaseFragment`).

Which leads us to a workaround by eliminating the `? :` construct

```
(value == null ? true : d.Status == 1)
```

with the equivalent

```
(value == null || d.Status == 1)
```

Comment: You can rewrite the query and eliminate `value == null` completely since it's just a local flag. It's not used in the query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm aware of that. I assume it was a simplified (and not very good chosen) example by OP. I also prefer the conditional `Where` approach, but it's not always applicable and also breaks the natural flow of the query syntax. At [one point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139402/the-type-appears-in-two-structurally-incompatible-initializations-within-a-singl/39140094#39140094) I've tried to get the best of the two by post processing the query expression tree, but haven't time to finalize the idea :)