# Ternary operator ?: in WHERE generates complex SQL by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I came across a strange behavior of Entity Framework.

When my code looks as follow:

```
var smithsOnly = false;
var partners = ctx.Partners.Where(x => !smithsOnly || x.LastName == "Smith").ToList();
```

the generated SQL is pretty obvious:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
    [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM [dbo].[PartnerEntities] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (@p__linq__0 <> 1) OR (N'Smith' = [Extent1].[LastName])
```

If I use ternary operator ? : instead and my code changes as follows:

```
var smithsOnly = false;
var partners = ctx.Partners.Where(x => smithsOnly ? x.LastName == "Smith" : true).ToList();
```

the SQL outcome is more complex as one could expect:

```
SELECT
  [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
  [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
FROM [dbo].[PartnerEntities] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (CASE
  WHEN (@p__linq__0 = 1) THEN CASE
      WHEN (N'Smith' = [Extent1].[LastName]) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
      WHEN (NOT ((N'Smith' = [Extent1].[LastName]) AND
        ([Extent1].[LastName] IS NOT NULL))) THEN CAST(0 AS bit)
    END
  ELSE CAST(1 AS bit)
END) = 1
```

I wonder, why Entity Framework adds the second `WHEN` in the innermost `CASE` with negation of the condition and *not-null* check and not simply `ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)`? I know that `=` operator in SQL Server acts diffrently as `==` in C# for null values (`NULL = NULL` delivers `NULL`, not `true`) but in my case a `Person` with `NULL` as `LastName` would be filtered out anyway, `'Smith'` is a constant, not a variable. When `[Extent1].[LastName]` would be compared to a variable or to other column as `[Extent1].[FirstName]` the additional `CASE` or `CASEs` with *not-null* check would be indeed needed.

Is this just missing performace tweak?

The queries above could be written in simpler way, it is just a simplification of a more complex query for problem presentation.

Comment: Just assuming, that the ternary operator works as a switch statement not a if-else that explains the would explain the double when.

Comment: Query translation is a complicated task. And no one is perfect. Once you know that imperfection, simply don't use ternary `bool` conditions.

Comment: It's not that the translation isn't perfect. The *query* itself is the problem. Catch-all queries that try to "dynamically" pass filters are bad in general, resulting in inefficient execution plans and very complex batches/stored procedures. In LINQ they are unnecessary since you can create the query dynamically already

Comment: If you want to create a more complex query you should explain what you want to do. You can chain multiple `Where` statements to create the equivalent of `AND` conditions. Creating `OR` is more complex. `Where` accepts an expression so if you know what type of conditions you want in advance you can create helper methods that return the expressions you want. If you want an open ended query generator though you may need a third-party library, or build the expressions in code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True and not true at the same time. Rather than asking you to do that (which is not so easy and even impossible inside complex query using LINQ query syntax), the perfect translator would do that for you. By "that" I mean partial evaluation and eliminating the constant predicate conditions. For instance, EF Core is trying to do something like that. So did I (probably naïve) a time ago here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139402/the-type-appears-in-two-structurally-incompatible-initializations-within-a-singl/39140094#39140094, but haven't time to finalize it.

Comment: @IvanStoev you are talking about optimization, not translation. There are experimental libraries that do that, but they remain that, experimental, because it's *hard*, expensive and can often lead to *worse* performance. That's why the *query optimizer* doesn't handle these cases and create eg two different execution plans when such predicates are encountered. Or 4,8,16 ... 2^n, depending on how many such conditions are there. As for EF Core, it doesn't even support GROUP BY yet.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But isn't that what all suggestions to build manually a query with conditional `Where` do (like the currently posted answer)? Or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248909/linq-query-with-conditional-join-and-non-anonymous-return. Why do something manually if the infrastructure can do that for you? Query translators perform many optimizations anyway (for instance eliminating multiple projections etc.)

Comment: @IvanStoev because *creating* the query to optimize is actually a lot *harder* than create the simple query. The only reason dead predicates are used is because that's the way the "dynamic parameter" hack in SQL stored procedures does. You *don't* need the hack if you can simply specify the criteria you want in code.

Answer (score 1):

You should create query dynamically. Something like this:

```
IQueryable<Partner> partners; // use the same type as ctx.Partners has

if (smithsOnly)
    partners = ctx.Partners.Where(x => x.LastName == "Smith");
else
    partners = ctx.Partners;

var list = partners.ToList();
```

Comment: `partners = smithsOnly ? ctx.Partners.Where(x => x.LastName == "Smith") : ctx.Partners;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I wrote in the last sentence, the point is not how to optimize the queries as they are only for ilustration.

Comment: @Wojtek actually, it *is* the point. You wrote a query that looks like the "dynamic conditions" hack that simply isn't needed when using LINQ or any other client-side ORM language that allows you to construct queries programmatically